# DynamicsGP 2010 eConnect Web Services GetList overwrites CustomerKey

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, dynamics-gp

I'm trying to return a list of Customers from GP using Web Services, however I'm running into a problem when executing the query. I can confirm that the main connection to the Dynamics database is working as I can run a query to retrieve the list of Companies (this is how I retrieved the CompanyID key to use with my context for the Customer query.)

However, when I execute any sort of other query, it looks like the CompanyKey is getting set to zero (0) in the XML being sent to eConnect. The exception returned is "Microsoft.Dynamics.Security.NonExistentSecurityObjectException : The security object does not exist.  Key = 0"   When I look at the xml being sent to the service, I notice that the  element is also set to 0, even though I explicitly set it the value of the Company I want to query (which in this case is 37 which I retrieved from doing the Company list query earlier.)

The full XML being sent is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RequestObjects>
  <Context xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/01">
    <OrganizationKey xsi:type="CompanyKey">
      <Id>0</Id>
    </OrganizationKey>
    <CurrencyType>Transactional</CurrencyType>
  </Context>
  <CustomerCriteria xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Scope>Return All</Scope>
  </CustomerCriteria>
</RequestObjects>
```

As for the underlying C# code I'm using in my client app:

```
CompanyKey companyKey;
Context context;
DynamicsGPClient wsDynamicsGP = new DynamicsGPClient();
context = new Context();
companyKey = new CompanyKey();
companyKey.Id = 37;
context.OrganizationKey = companyKey;
companies = wsDynamicsGP.GetCustomerList( new CustomerCriteria { }, context );
```

I've based my code on the examples given in the GP2010 Web Services developers manually straight from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the keys in GP and in the actice directory database in web services are the same. Its probably a missing key in web services.

There is a techknowledge on this with the SQL queries you need to run:

https://mbs.microsoft.com/knowledgebase/KBDisplay.aspx?WTNTZSMNWUKNTMMYVLXUZLWUKKQPOVRVTLKUSRMOQVVYUKKXRVYRTTWLZTPWKURU

Answer (score 0):

```
get company id

SELECT CMPNYNAM, INTERID, CMPANYID
    FROM DYNAMICS.dbo.SY01500
```

If company id math then make repair web service. After this in IIS set basic authentication to enabled

In my case this solution helped.